# How to make import using unique_together?

Tags: django, django-import-export

I need to make an import using not only the id field but also the brand field. So that products can exist with the same ID but a different brand

```
class Part(models.Model):
    brand = models.CharField('Производитель', max_length=100, blank=True, default='Нет производителя')
    id = models.CharField('Артикул', max_length=100, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField('Название', max_length=100, blank=True, default='Нет имени')
    description = models.TextField('Комментарий', blank=True, max_length=5000, default='Нет описания')
    analog = models.ManyToManyField('self', through='ContactConnection',blank=True, related_name='AnalogParts')
    analog = models.ManyToManyField('self',blank=True, related_name='AnalogParts')
    images = models.FileField('Главное изображение', upload_to = 'parts/', blank=True)
    images0 = models.FileField('Дополнительное фото', upload_to = 'parts/', blank=True)
    images1 = models.FileField('Дополнительное фото', upload_to = 'parts/', blank=True)
    images2 = models.FileField('Дополнительное фото', upload_to = 'parts/', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Запчасть'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Запчасти'
        unique_together = [['id', 'brand']]

class PartConnection(models.Model):
    to_part = models.ForeignKey(Part, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='to_parts')
    from_part = models.ForeignKey(Part, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='from_parts')
```

Comment: Since your `id` is the primary key, that is unique, so `unique_together` makes no sense, since the `id` itself should be guaranteed unique already.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem 
but how then is it possible to add 2 products with the same ID

Comment: `id` field already provided by django itself try other name for your 'id' like `product_id`

Comment: @ShiBilPK my ID is provided by user